# If a web browser evals javascript code received from an ajax call how do I see the code that was evaled?

Tags: javascript, security

If a web browser receives javascript code from an ajax or websocket connection, and then eval said code, how do I see or intercept the code that was evaled?

Comment: The usual way would be to add some code in the existing [XHR onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload) or the [WebSocket onmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onmessage) event handler.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You might want to elaborate a little more on your answer.  Provide a few more specifics and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome Developer Tools, dynamically executed code is shown in the Sources tab as a fake source file with a name of the form `VM:####`, where `####` is an arbitrary number.

You can also put a comment like:

```
//# sourceURL=filename.js
```

in the code that's evaluated. It will then emulate that the code was loaded from a file with the given name. This is useful for setting breakpoints, since a breakpoint set in a previous load will be used in a later load of the same `sourceURL`.